# Is it possible to apply two matching pattern transformations in one operation?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash variable populated with a filename and path:

```
SONG="~/Music/Mine/Cool Title Bro.flac"
```

In my attempts to make tagging dramatically easier, I applied a bit of transformation to the variable to isolate the title:

```
echo "${SONG#\~/Music/Mine/}" # which prints: Cool Title Bro.flac
```

I know it's also possible to remove the suffix with `${SONG%%.flac}`.

But is it possible to remove both the prefix and the suffix in a single operation?

This:

```
${SONG#\~/Music/Mine/%%.flac}
```

doesn't work presumably because it tries to match a literal `%%.flac` as part of the prefix. The reverse does not work (`%%.flac#~/[...]`), and I've even gone crazy and tried

```
${${SONG#~/Music/Mine/}%%.flac}
```

which also does not work.

This may be a prime example of over-engineering on my part, but it'd be excellent if there is a way to do this and I just haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: I had a very quick run through http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html and I think that you may have to do this in two separate steps using bash's variable substitution operators. Also note that I had to escape the forward slashes in echo "${SONG#\~/Music\/Mine\/" to get that front end replacement to work. I used GNU bash, version 4.1.10(4)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)

Comment: @RobKielty: I only had to escape the tilde. Notice that you're not escaping the first slash.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson You are correct, upon further inspection I only had to escape the ~

Comment: Sorry, variable data changed to protect the innocent, but in doing so created another issue. :). Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo "1:"
if [[ "$SONG" =~ \~/Music/Mine/(.*)\.flac ]] ; then SONG=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ; fi
echo $SONG

echo "2:"
[[ "$SONG" =~ \~/Music/Mine/(.*)\.flac ]] && SONG=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
echo $SONG
```

1 and 2 use bash regular expressions.  The first example has the added advantage of being able to break into an `else` branch if your string doesn't match the format thats expected.*  The second example is a bit cleaner.  In both cases, if `${SONG}` doesn't match the pattern, it is left unchanged.

But using awk or sed might be easier to understand.  For example:

```
echo "3:"
SONG=$(echo "$SONG" | sed -r 's:~/Music/Mine/(.*)\.flac:\1:')
echo $SONG
```

[*] *See DennisWilliamson's note below regarding using `||` to get an `else` branch.*

Comment: It just needs escaping. `[[ $song =~ \~/Music/Mine/(.*).flac ]]`

Comment: +1 You can do `else` with the second version by adding `|| foo` at the end. Although the OP wants a single operation, it's usually better to put the regex in a variable. Also, the dot should be escaped to make it literal `\.flac`. The curly braces around `SONG` are superfluous here. Always quote variables when they are expanded: `echo "$SONG".

Comment: +1 for the first two examples. I think it's always good to explore fully the capabilities of bash and avoid where possible resorting to forking and exec-ing a subshell then forking and exec-ing echo, creating a pipe then forking and exec-ing sed and returning the result to the parent bash process.

Answer (score 3):

In some cases, `bash`'s extended patterns are flexible enough to accomplish what you want. First, you have to turn them on:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Then, you can specify a list of patterns that should be removed using parameter expansion:

```
echo ${SONG//@(*\/|.*)}
```

The extended pattern `@(*\/|.*)` matches *either* everything up to a / (which must be escaped, to avoid confusing it with part of the parameter substitution syntax), *or* a period and everything following it. The `//` indicates that each occurrence of the pattern should be substituted.

Answer (score 2):

No, not possible. Use two operations.

```
tmp="${SONG#\~/Music/Mine/}"; echo "${tmp%.flac}"
```

Well ok, it's possible, if you're nuts.

```
a="~/Music/Mine/Cool Title Bro.flac"
echo "${a:b=$(b=${a%${a#\~/Music/Mine/}};echo ${#b}):$(c=${a%.flac};echo ${#c})-b}"
```

You could also use regex grouping in a shell that supports it. Example in [jedwards answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11115624/495451)

It can also be done using ksh93 pattern grouping.

```
song='~/Music/Mine/Cool Title Bro.flac'; echo "${song/'~/Music/Mine/'+(*).flac/\1}"
```

Comment: "Considered overkill"?  I think regular expressions would hands down be the preferred method over your second example at least.  Also, with regex, you are able to detect and catch the case where the string ***doesn't*** match what you expect.  You can't do that with either of your examples.

Comment: @jedwards Regex is ok. It's a big clunky syntax for doing a simple transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's hoping I didn't misunderstand your question. You want to isolate "Cool Title Bro"?
If so, then

```
$ echo "~/Music/Mine/Cool Title Bro.flac"
~/Music/Mine/Cool Title Bro.flac
$ echo "~/Music/Mine/Cool Title Bro.flac"|sed 's/.*\/\(.*\).flac/\1/'
Cool Title Bro
```

Nothing a little regex can't manage.
Or alternatively

```
$ echo "~/Music/Mine/Cool Title Bro.flac"|sed 's/.*\/\(.*\)\..*/\1/'
Cool Title Bro
```

To work with any file extension.

Answer (score -1):

If i should do it in only one line, and i don't care about legibility i will use

```
echo "${SONG:13:${#SONG} - 18}"
```

where

- 13 is the length of the string "~/Music/Mine/"
- 18 is the length of the string "~/Music/Mine/" plus the length of ".flac"

A more easy application of this string manipulation in bash will be:

```
$ TEST="1234567890"
$ echo ${TEST:3}
4567890
$ echo ${TEST:3:4}
4567
```

Comment: We don't know the length of the substring so this method can't be used.

Comment: You don't have to know the length of the substring, just the length of the extension that you want to remove, and the length of the path. I edit my post as there are a bug on it. Anyway the length can be dynamically get with the wc command

Comment: It's not necessary to use `wc`: `echo "${SONG:13:${#SONG} - 18}"`